# Do Engi extinguish fires faster?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Engi are naturally faster at making repairs. Does extinguishing fires count as a repair action?

Comment: To add to that, do you gain experience from extinguishing a fire?

Comment: I added my own answer which includes this part, and the answer seems to be no. Experience helps you put out the fires, but isn't gained from doing so.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

My answer to your question is two-fold: it works on the output end, but not on the experience end. I watched the repair experience meter as my crewmember put out a large fire, and nothing changed. However, it does seem like their effectiveness at extinguishing it relies on that repair skill. In response to your edit, I would assume that yes, classes more suited to repairs are more suited to putting out fires. However, I have no clue if the Rockman attribute of stomping on fires affects this.

Comment: More succinctly, experience aides extinguishing, but is not gained for doing so.

Answer (score 38):

My answer to this question will be **Yes, extinguishing fires counts as repairing**. My current repair-skill-upgraded Engi extinguishes fire squares in less than a second per square. The only explanation is that fires are treated as repair actions.

**Thanks @Winterswift and @Aslum for the additional information**

Apparently while extinguishing DOES count as a repair action, and receives benifits from leveling the repair statistic, it does not give experience as if the crew-member actually repaired something.

So:

- Manti will extinguish at half speed.
- Engi will extinguish twice as fast.
- Rocks extinguish at normal speed, but are immune to the fire damage whilst doing so.
- Upgrading any crew member's repair stat will improve their extinguishing speed.
- Extinguishing fire will *not* grant repair stat or any other experience.

Comment: From data-mining the game, it's now been learned that Rockmen have an innate +67% bonus to putting out fires that's separate from repair skill, making them almost as good as Engi at extinguishing fires (unless it's time-critical and involves a foot race). Crystals, on the other hand, are actually 17% slower at putting out fires.